# Setting Cursor.Current but some external windows changing it to "disabled" icon

Tags: c#, windows, cursor

I'm using Cursor.Current to change the cursor icon to my own custom bitmap when I'm doing a drag-and-drop operation.  This works fine except for the fact that when I move the cursor over some external windows as I'm dragging the icon is changed to the disabled icon (circle with a cross through it).  I need to be able to maintain my custom bitmap as the icon during this drag-and-drop operation regardless of which window I drag it over.

How can I get my cursor to remain my custom bitmap regardless of which external window the mouse is hovering over?

Comment: Is this during a drag-and-drop operation? If so, the "no entry" sign showing up is standard and you shouldn't attempt to change it.

Comment: Yes, it is during a drag-and-drop operation. Let's assume I need to change it - is it possible?

Comment: How, then, is the user meant to get feedback on locations where the drop can succeed?

Comment: For the purposes of my app the drop can "succeed" on any window. It's really not doing a copy - it's just reporting back which window handle the "drop" occurred on.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is the sender in the drag/drop communication. The object is being dragged from your application and dropped on the other application. That means that your application has no say in the state of the cursor when it is over a potential drop target. Drag and drop is a cooperative process. The target has to consent to having something dropped on it. If the target doesn't want your object to be dropped on it, the system will let the user know by means of the cursor.

All this means that drag and drop is the wrong way to implement the UI that you desire. You need to stop using drag and drop. Instead you need to capture the mouse and paint your icon on the screen whilst the user is "dragging" it. Your requirement seems to be to implement something akin to the Spy++ window finder. This article shows how to do it: [Code Project, MS Spy++ style Window Finder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1698/MS-Spy-style-Window-Finder).

Comment: Yes, that looks like it. I see it's using a dialog containing the image as it is dragged around the screen. How would I do that in C#? Some sort of custom MessageBox?

Comment: I don't know. Probably quite tricky in C#. I think we are now moving on from the question that you asked.